# comma separating the texts of link buttons

Tags: jquery

i am storing the names of a series of link buttons having common class in an array and printing the value of array in a span but as all linkbuttons have common classes so they are getting stored as a single entry in the array and while printing the value it is not getting comma separated

the markup that is the aspx part is some what like this

```
<div class="rightSortControl">
            <asp:Label ID="lblFilterLabel" runat="server" 
                CssClass="sortLabel" Text="View:">
            </asp:Label>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnToBePublished" runat="server"
                Text="To Be Published" CssClass="filterButton" Visible="false" 
                OnCommand="doSomething"/>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnBookmarkedByMe" runat="server"
                Text="Bookmarked" CssClass="filterButton" Visible="false" 
                OnCommand="doSomething"/>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnAuthoredByMeFilter" runat="server" 
                Text="Authored by Me" CssClass="filterButton" 
                OnCommand="doSomething"/>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnTakenByMe" runat="server" 
                Text="Taken by Me" CssClass="filterButton" Visible="false" 
                OnCommand="doSomething"/>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnTakingInProgress" runat="server"
                Text="Taking" CssClass="filterButton" Visible="false" 
                OnCommand="doSomething"/>
        </div>
```

here the class mentioned is 'filterbutton' which i am changing dynamically whenever the user click on those linkbuttons to 'selectedButton'.

```
$('.rightSortControl').each(function()
{
    if ($(this).find('.selectedButton').length > 0)
    {
        arrAppliedFilter.push($.trim($(this).find('.selectedButton').text()));
    }
});

alert(arrAppliedFilter); //not comma separating the names what to do
```

what i have to do to fix this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well i got the answer i was doing a mistake over there

```
$('.rightSortControl').find('a.selectedButton').each(function()
{
    arrAppliedFilter.push($.trim($(this).text()));
});
```

and it is working fine any ways thanks everybody for your support

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Array join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) method:

```
alert(arrAppliedFilter.join(','));
```

Comment: Mac: Can you check if the array contains only one element? What does `arrAppliedFilter.length` return?

Comment: @mac How are you changing the class to `selectedButton`?

Comment: that i mention in code behind i am changing the class onCommand Event of link buttons actually it is storing all the names as a single array value i dont know why

Comment: i got the solution and posted that as answer but any ways thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

```
alert(arrAppliedFilter.join(','));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var message = [ 'foo', 'bar' ];
message.join(',');
console.log(message);
```

Using `alert()` to dump a value can often mislead. The result depends on the browser's specific implementation of `alert()`. For example, in Google Chrome v10.0.648.45 dev, `alert(message)` results in a message box containing `foo,bar`. Note the comma. Though it is not present in the `message` variable, the box displays it. Hence for more reliability when looking into (dumping) data structures, use `console.log()` (if your browser supports it).

Comment: i am not exactly alerting those array values i am showing them in a span somewhat like this $('.showFilter').text('Currently Applied Filters : ' + arrAppliedFilter);